# VS 2013 publish to Azure can't copy Microsoft.mshtml.dll

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013

I have an MVC app I'm trying to publish to Azure. When I do the publish, I get this message:

> Copying file bin\Microsoft.mshtml.dll to obj\Debug\AspnetCompileMerge\Source\bin\Microsoft.mshtml.dll failed. Could not find file 'bin\Microsoft.mshtml.dll'.

I'm not sure where `Microsoft.mshtml.dll` is required/used. And I'm not sure where to include it so the Publish will work.

Here's the output from the Build that references Microsoft.mshtml:

3>  AssemblyFiles:
3>      C:\Projects\BitLocker\publicationsystem\IAuditable\bin\Debug\EntityFramework.Auditing.dll
3>      C:\Projects\BitLocker\publicationsystem\MkpTools\bin\Debug\PublicationSystem.Tools.dll
3>      C:\Projects\BitLocker\publicationsystem\PublicationSystem.DynamicForms\bin\Debug\PublicationSystem.DynamicForms.dll
3>      C:\Projects\BitLocker\publicationsystem\PublicationSystem.Extensions\bin\Debug\PublicationSystem.Extensions.dll
3>      C:\Projects\BitLocker\publicationsystem\PublicationSystem.Model\bin\Debug\PublicationSystem.Model.dll
3>      C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\mscorlib.dll
3>  CandidateAssemblyFiles:
3>      bin\AutoMapper.dll
3>      bin\DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll
3>      bin\EntityFramework.Auditing.dll
3>      bin\EntityFramework.dll
3>      bin\EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll
3>      bin\ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.dll
3>      bin\Magick.NET-x86.dll
3>      bin\Magick.NET.Core.dll
3>      bin\Magick.NET.Web-x86.dll
3>      bin\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core.dll
3>      bin\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.dll
3>      bin\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.dll
**3>      bin\Microsoft.mshtml.dll**
3>      bin\Microsoft.Owin.dll
3>      bin\Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.dll
3>      bin\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.dll
3>      bin\Microsoft.Owin.Security.dll
3>      bin\Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.dll
3>      bin\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll
3>      bin\Microsoft.Web.Administration.dll
3>      bin\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll
3>      bin\MvcSiteMapProvider.dll
3>      bin\MvcSiteMapProvider.WebActivator.dll
3>      bin\Newtonsoft.Json.dll
3>      bin\Owin.dll
3>      bin\PublicationSystem.dll
3>      bin\PublicationSystem.DynamicForms.dll
3>      bin\PublicationSystem.Extensions.dll
3>      bin\PublicationSystem.Model.dll
3>      bin\PublicationSystem.Tools.dll
3>      bin\PublicationSystem_Test.dll
3>      bin\Spire.Doc.dll
3>      bin\Spire.License.dll
3>      bin\Spire.Pdf.dll
3>      bin\System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll
3>      bin\System.Web.Helpers.dll
3>      bin\System.Web.Http.dll
3>      bin\System.Web.Http.WebHost.dll
3>      bin\System.Web.Mvc.dll
3>      bin\System.Web.Optimization.dll
3>      bin\System.Web.Razor.dll
3>      bin\System.Web.Webpages.Deployment.dll
3>      bin\System.Web.Webpages.dll
3>      bin\System.Web.Webpages.Razor.dll
3>      bin\T4MVCExtensions.dll
3>      bin\WebActivatorEx.dll
3>      bin\WebGrease.dll
...

3>      Using this version instead of original version "2.0.0.0" in "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Azure.NET SDK\v2.9\bin\plugins\Diagnostics\Microsoft.Web.Administration.dll" because there is a more recent version of this framework file.
**3>      Using this version instead of original version "1.0.3300.0" in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft.NET\Primary Interop Assemblies\Microsoft.mshtml.dll" because there is a more recent version of this framework file.**
3>      Resolved file path is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\mscorlib.dll".
3>      Reference found at search path location "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\mscorlib.dll".
3>      This reference is not "CopyLocal" because it's a prerequisite file.
3>      The ImageRuntimeVersion for this reference is "v4.0.30319".
...

3>      Reference found at search path location "{TargetFrameworkDirectory}".
3>          For SearchPath "{CandidateAssemblyFiles}".
3>          Considered "bin\AutoMapper.dll", but its name "AutoMapper" didn't match.
3>          Considered "bin\DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll", but its name "DocumentFormat.OpenXml" didn't match.
3>          Considered "bin\EntityFramework.Auditing.dll", but its name "EntityFramework.Auditing" didn't match.
3>          Considered "bin\EntityFramework.dll", but its name "EntityFramework" didn't match.
3>          Considered "bin\EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll", but its name "EntityFramework.SqlServer" didn't match.
3>          Considered "bin\ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.dll", but its name "ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib" didn't match.
3>          Considered "bin\Magick.NET-x86.dll", but its name "Magick.NET-x86" didn't match.
3>          Considered "bin\Magick.NET.Core.dll", but its name "Magick.NET.Core" didn't match.
3>          Considered "bin\Magick.NET.Web-x86.dll", but its name "Magick.NET.Web-x86" didn't match.
3>          Considered "bin\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core.dll", but its name "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core" didn't match.
3>          Considered "bin\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.dll", but its name "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework" didn't match.
3>          Considered "bin\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.dll", but its name "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin" didn't match.
**3>          Considered "bin\Microsoft.mshtml.dll", but its name "Microsoft.mshtml" didn't match.**
3>          Considered "bin\Microsoft.Owin.dll", but its name "Microsoft.Owin" didn't match.
3>          Considered "bin\Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.dll", but its name "Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb" didn't match.
3>          Considered "bin\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.dll", but its name "Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" didn't match.
3>          Considered "bin\Microsoft.Owin.Security.dll", but its name "Microsoft.Owin.Security" didn't match.
3>          Considered "bin\Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.dll", but its name "Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" didn't match.
3>          Considered "bin\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll", but its name "Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework" didn't match.
...

3>      Reference found at search path location "{CandidateAssemblyFiles}".
3>          For SearchPath "{CandidateAssemblyFiles}".
3>          Considered "bin\AutoMapper.dll", but its name "AutoMapper" didn't match.
3>          Considered "bin\DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll", but its name "DocumentFormat.OpenXml" didn't match.
3>          Considered "bin\EntityFramework.Auditing.dll", but its name "EntityFramework.Auditing" didn't match.
3>          Considered "bin\EntityFramework.dll", but its name "EntityFramework" didn't match.
3>          Considered "bin\EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll", but its name "EntityFramework.SqlServer" didn't match.
3>          Considered "bin\ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.dll", but its name "ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib" didn't match.
3>          Considered "bin\Magick.NET-x86.dll", but its name "Magick.NET-x86" didn't match.
3>          Considered "bin\Magick.NET.Core.dll", but its name "Magick.NET.Core" didn't match.
3>          Considered "bin\Magick.NET.Web-x86.dll", but its name "Magick.NET.Web-x86" didn't match.
3>          Considered "bin\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core.dll", but its name "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core" didn't match.
3>          Considered "bin\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.dll", but its name "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework" didn't match.
3>          Considered "bin\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.dll", but its name "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin" didn't match.
**3>          Considered "bin\Microsoft.mshtml.dll", but its name "Microsoft.mshtml" didn't match.**
3>      The ImageRuntimeVersion for this reference is "v4.0.30319".
3>  Primary reference "Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb, Version=3.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35".

Comment: I don't see Microsoft.html in the references node.

Comment: I don't know what Microsoft.MsHtml is even being used for. I'm looking for documentation on what `Considered "bin\Microsoft.mshtml.dll", but its name "Microsoft.mshtml" didn't match.` means. Searching for that doesn't show much.

Comment: My other question is, why do I need this (and other files) that are erroring? If the site compiles and runs locally, what are they used for during publish? Why are so many deployment processes black boxes with poor documentation?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to move ahead.

Since this (and other files) were not necessary to run the app, I simply did a search on my PC for all the files (and there were several) that Publish said it couldn't find. When I found them, I copied them to the bin folder of my project. This took a while, since the Publish function complained one file at a time. (Error, copy, try again, error, etc.)

I'm only thankful Microsoft doesn't build cars and/or airbags.